# fix the range of axis values in plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am plotting the accuracy and loss figures.
I am getting the following plot that represents 3 places after 0 like 0.XXX I aim to present only one like 0.X

how can I fix this

```
acc = history.history['accuracy']
acc_val = history.history['val_accuracy']
epochs = range(len(acc))
plt.title('Training and Validation accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[accuracy figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4jRV.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter

acc = history.history['accuracy']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot([i for i in range(len(acc))], acc)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.1f'))
plt.show()
```

But you may see multiple ticks with the same value. Alternatively or in addition you can use the below to limit the ticks to what you want to be shown:

```
ax.set_yticks([0.8, 0.9, 1.0])
```

Comment: I tried both ways but nothing changed in the graph

Comment: Sorry, for a second I got confused as to what exactly the problem is. I edited my answer and hepfully this will solve your problem.